# Racing jibe in windsurfing

Tags: windsurfing

How to do a racing jibe in windsurfing ? What is the better type of sail to try to do is first racing jibe (wave sail or slalom sail) ?

You can see a video of the professional windsurfer Anders Bringdal [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCTzbQdE4G0&playnext=1&list=PLA2B6FC99FCC18D1E&feature=results_main).

Waves sail pro:

- strong
- maneuvrability

Waves sail cons:

- heavy

Slalom sail pro

- stable
- accelerate in the gust

Slalom sail cons

- fragility
- less maneuverability.

Comment: The tag sail is not adequate, a tag windsurf would be better.

Comment: Tagged as "windsurfing." Welcome to Sports SE! What have you tried? What are racing jibes? More detail will help us answer your question. Also, answers may have different opinions about wave vs. slalom sails...perhaps it would be helpful to ask the pros/cons of type of sail vs. "what is better." Please see our [FAQ](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: Seems like your in the process to answering your own question?

Comment: Good edit. As Zack says, if you can answer your own question, by all means, you are free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

- Slalom sail

  These sails are all about speed. If you want to travel fast, get a Slalom sail. They reach such high speed because they have special "chambers" that are inside the sail and clip onto the mast. Although speed comes with a price since you do have to exert a little more effort to turn this type of sail

  Tuning a Slalom sail to extract maximum speed is great fun and can become a technical as you'd like.   Many of the pro's record measurements such as boom height, downhaul and outhaul after each session so they can accurately reproduce a sweet setting.   Most slalom/speed sails are from 6.0 to 10.0 meters.
- Wave sail

  Wave sales are built for somebody who is starting out in the sport. They are meant to get beat up. generally reinforced to be able to handle the beating they'll receive when you get it wrong. If you wreck with this type of sail, it will come out of the water perfectly fine, unlike the slalom which might be in pieces. Wave sails are also very easy to handle, which makes turning a lot easier. The rear of the sale is also cut high to avoid getting it caught in surf. The downside for wave sails is that you don't get the speed of a slalom sail. But it is more sturdy, easier to handle and great for beginners. Sizes are generally 3.5 to 5.5 meters